# VBA trigger enter or update lookup values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the following code:

```
Sub PrintToCSV()
    Dim i As Long, e As Long
    i = Worksheets("STATEMENT (2)").Range("$G$6").Value
    e = Worksheets("STATEMENT (2)").Range("$G$7").Value

    Do While i <= e
        Range("K6") = i
        Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

        If Range("$X$10").Value > 0 Then
            Cells(1, 1).Value = i
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

It loops and changes value of `Range("K6")` as expected. However, the value of `Range("K6")` updates other cells values (vlookup) when I do it manually, but not with this code. How can I ensure the values of other cells depended on `Range("K6")` changes with this code?

Comment: Put `Application.Calculate` after `Range("K6") = i`

Comment: @Scott Craner still no luck... it only updates values on the first iteration and then it's just shows `#N/A` error for the rest....

Comment: It may be better to then put the formula in the code instead of a constant query to the worksheet.

Comment: ▲ yeah ... this ▲

Comment: @Scott Craner it could be, but there are hundreds lookups and calculations... from 3 different tabs too... is there any other way?

Comment: What is the formula in X10?

Comment: Worksheet(1).Columns(1).Calculate or Worksheet(1).Calculate?

Comment: @Scott Craner X10 is a sum of column Y, which depends on K6 (account number). `Worksheets("STATEMENT (2)").Calculate` didn't work either.

Comment: What is the exact formula you use? You may think it is not important but going down the route of constantly changing a value in one cell and finding the result in another cell to test is clunky and slow.  It would be much sleeker and quicker to do the calculation in vba to test.  You can still change the value in K6 but test the results in vba directly.

Comment: @Scott Craner `X10 =IFERROR(SUM(Y:Y),0)` i'm not too familiar with VBA... my final target is: set range of accounts to go thru. change data accordingly in `while` loop. find the last row used. set range. save range into a CSV file. next account.

Comment: I assume that column Y is filled with VLOOKUPS that refer to K6?  What is that formula?

Comment: @Scott Craner there are formulas and vlookups form M to X and Y is just a sum of them...

Comment: Would `Workbook("your workbook name.xls").RefreshAll` not work? I know that method works for data ranges, would it not update formulas?

Comment: I can *only* replicate this with a test worksheet (at least not in Excel 2013) if  `Application.Calculation` is set to `xlCalculationManual`. Try removing the `Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)` (it isn't doing anything other than making it take longer to execute) and put `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the top of the `Sub`.

Comment: @Comintern it's not doing anything at the moment, but my script will enlarge. and yes i tried all of available calculations already. and Manual is not what i'm looking for

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot of your WS? it will help to recreate your scenario. When I try to replicate your scenario, it works for me (although my table is tiny)

Comment: @Zac hi! you can see the formulas in here... to many to put in the script..... any suggestions will help - https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fn6oz0avjj9gmb/Elen%20-%20excel%20snapshot.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Here are a few other options for recalculating. The first I'd try is `Application.CalculateFull` or try setting the `ForceFullCalculation` of a `WorkBook` to True. Like: `ThisWorkBook.ForceFullCalculation = True`. Using the `ForceFullCalculation` property may increase calculation time. See this for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823189.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access dropbox from work (it's blocked). Quick question though, I'm presuming that you have multiple worksheets in your workbook? If so, when you assign a value to `Range("K6") = 1`, does it update the correct worksheet?

Comment: I've used tricks similar to this before. Try replacing `Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)` with `Do While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone: Loop`. This should act as a "do-nothing" loop until all calculations have been completed.

Comment: Is i the invoice/sales number you are iterating on?

Comment: @Matt Cremeens but that just going to wait forever? It doesn't actually force recalculate? i tried this and it does nothing.... sorry

Comment: @Kevin yes it's going up by one

Comment: `Application.Calculate` is your first port of call. After that, it's `Application.CalculateFullRebuild`  - you don't want to call that continuously on a timer, so make sure it's only called when `Range("$X$10").Value > 0` is true. The need for 'Full Rebuild' is a hint that your formulas have a lot of Lookup and Indirect functions (or other sources of volatility)  that are making the calculation tree excessively complex.

Comment: @Elen it should just wait until the calculations are done. Perhaps you have so many calculations that it just seems like it is waiting forever.

Comment: @Zac when i first run the script it updates correctly for the first iteration, then it changes to "#N/A" and doesn't do the job

Comment: @Nile the range `"$X$10"` will only find out whether it's more than 0 after other fields are recalculated based on value of `Range("K6")`

Comment: @Matt Cremeens i waited. nothing happens. no errors either.

Comment: how long does it take to calculate when you change k6 manually?

Comment: @Kevin a split second - it's just looking up values from other worksheets form the same workbook

Comment: @Elen how long did you wait? Did "Calculating" still appear in the bottom left hand corner of your workbook?

Comment: @Matt Cremeens no.. i don't see any messages and it is still "on" since your first message

Comment: `Do While i <= e
        Worksheets("STATEMENT (2)").Calculate
Do While Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone
            
            Range("$K$6") = i
    
            If Range("$X$10").Value > 0 Then
                Cells(1, 1).Value = i
            End If
        Loop
        i = i + 1
    Loop`

Comment: @Elen looks like you are missing the `: Loop` in the code I provided.

Comment: @Matt Cremeens yes sorry. corrected and re-ran. nothing updating... can it possibly be something like type mismatch? (i.e. i do integer and look up table store it as text?)

Comment: I'm not sure. At this point, it might be best if we could access the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Elen No, a type mismatch would not stop the updates or code since the vlookup is on the worksheet. You'd just get an error on the worksheet instead.

Comment: Guys it WAS a type mismatch. i converted account number in look up table to number and it now runs and updates as expected. thank you for all your help! I will answer my own question later...

Comment: @Elen Guess I stand corrected. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lays in the type mismatch. `Range("K6")` value is a long integer, while lookup table stored account numbers as text. Converting text to a number solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Just FYI - do not declare like this:

```
Dim i, e as Long
```

because for this declaration only "e" is declared as long and "i" as a variant. This may cause problems somewhere later.[image]

The correct way is:

```
Dim i as Long
Dim e as Long
```

Comment: ok cheers for the note. I declare it as `Dim i As Long, e As Long`

Answer (score 1):

Here you got a bug in your code because `i` type was undefined. And this should be fixed with [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/y9341s4f.aspx) - if we were in pure [vb](/questions/tagged/vb).

This is a common declaration issue where ***we assume [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)*** will read

```
Dim i,e as long
```

as

```
Dim i as long
Dim e as long
...
```

Unfortunately it doesn't. It is weird, because **it differs from the way it works in [vb](/questions/tagged/vb)**:

> *Declaring Multiple Variables*
>
> You can declare several variables in one declaration statement, specifying the variable name for each one, and following each array name with parentheses. Multiple variables are separated by commas.
>
> ```
> Dim lastTime, nextTime, allTimes() As Date
> ```

**In VBA, to be sure of the type**, we can get check the type of the variable that way with `TypeName`:

```
Sub getTypes()
    Dim i, e As Long
    MsgBox "i: " & TypeName(i)
    MsgBox "e: " & TypeName(e)
End Sub
```

give:

```
i: Empty
e: Long
```

Comment: thanks.... but you should check others answers before posting your own. please see Vityata answer....